# Storm shuffle grouping not distributing evenly

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have a simple storm topology which mainly consists of two bolts:

BatchPricingRequestReaderBolt - takes a batch request and emits a tuple for each individual pricing request in the batch.

PricingRequestHandlerBolt - values the pricing request.

I have one BatchPricingRequestReaderBolt and four PricingRequestHandlerBolts.

The PricingRequestHandlerBolt is added as a shuffleGrouping on the BatchPricingRequestReaderBolt.

In the case where my batch request has four pricing requests, I would expect all four PricingRequestHandlerBolts to run at the same time - each one handling one tuple. However that is not what I observe. Sometimes it works like that but most of the time it only uses three or two of the PricingRequestHandlerBolts.

Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: Here is some simple code that demonstrates the problem. I would expect all four tuples to be handled at the same time but that is not what happens the majority of the time.

```
import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.generated.StormTopology;
import org.apache.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import org.apache.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import org.apache.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;

import java.util.Map;

public class SimpleStormTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        builder.setSpout("TestSpout", new TestSpout(), 1);
        builder.setBolt("TestBolt", new TestBolt(), 4)
                .shuffleGrouping("TestSpout");

        StormTopology topology = builder.createTopology();
        Config conf = new Config();

        conf.setNumWorkers(5);

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("LocalTopology", conf, topology);
    }

    public static class TestSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
        private transient SpoutOutputCollector collector;
        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
            System.out.println("%%% open " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            this.collector = collector;
        }

        @Override
        public void nextTuple() {
            System.out.println("nextTuple");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10_000);
                int valueToEmit = counter;
                counter++;
                collector.emit(new Values(valueToEmit));
                collector.emit(new Values(valueToEmit));
                collector.emit(new Values(valueToEmit));
                collector.emit(new Values(valueToEmit));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
            declarer.declare(new Fields("Input"));
        }
    }

    public static class TestBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
        private transient OutputCollector collector;

        @Override
        public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
            this.collector = collector;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(Tuple input) {
            System.out.println("!!! Executing " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                collector.emit(new Values(input.getValueByField("Input")));
                collector.ack(input);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
            declarer.declare(new Fields("Result"));
        }
    }
}
```

I expect I just don't understand some basic concept because otherwise this would be a very serious problem.

Edit 2: I've written my own grouping now that behaves as I would expect but I think this is such a common use case there must be something fundamental I just don't get.

Comment: It's hard to tell if there's anything wrong unless you post your topology setup code. I think ShuffleGrouping will in some cases not spread tuples evenly, but that's an attempt at avoiding locking in the grouping implementation, since multiple threads may use the grouping at the same time. See the implementation at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/grouping/ShuffleGrouping.java

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll extract the logic into a simple project and update the question.